# как сохранить файл через команду Save

Tags: python, tkinter

Надеюсь все знают как работает пункт меню `Save`. На всякий поясню. Если файл пустой он запрашивает команду `filedialog.asksaveasfile()`. Меня больше интересует когда ты сохранил файл через команду, указанную выше, а потом нажал `Save`, то программа не должна сохранять как `filedialog.asksaveasfile()`, а сохраняет уже по заданному пути.

Как это осуществить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

это функция сохраняет файл через save as

```
def save_as():
    f=filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w',filetypes = (("new files","*.pain"),("all files","*.*")),
                            defaultextension='.pain')                
if f != None:
    a=text.get('1.0',END+'-1c')
t=text.get(0.0,END)
try:
    f.write(t.rstrip())
except:
    messagebox.showerror('Fault!','Fail not saved')
root.title(os.path.basename(f.name) + ' - HEAD PAIN EDITOR')
```

А это функция должна сохранять данные в тот же файл
 def save():

```
file= open(f,'w')
a=text.get('1.0',END+'-1c')
if w == True:
    f=filedialog.asksaveasfile(filetypes = (("new files","*.pain"),("all files","*.*")),
                            defaultextension='.pain') 
    a=text.get('1.0',END+'-1c')
    file.close()
else:
    file.write(a)
    file.close
```

то что вы говорили про локальную переменную, если я создам f=filedialog.asksaveasfile(filetypes = (("new files","*.pain"),("all files","*.*")),
                            defaultextension='.pain')  во второй функции, то это не будет соответствовать мои требованием
надо чтобы вторая функция проверила сохранен или этот файл и если нет то сохранить не вызывая метод asksaveasfile

Comment: ну просто можно сохранять в переменную путь  и при сейве ее вызывать. Вы же когда файл открываете вы же путь ему указываете

Comment: "Вы же когда файл открываете вы же путь ему указываете". Нет я не указываю путь. я его указываю только через команду описанную  выше.

Comment: а как вы файл открываете?

Comment: А также мне надо как-то проверить был ли файл уже сохранён. То есть если файл уже сохранен, то по нажатию на сайв данные  перебрасываются в этот файл, а если файл не сохранён то сохраняем через команду указаную выше. Как-так. Если это чем то поможет, то я создал свой текстовый редактор. Помогите решить эту проблему пожалуйсто

Comment: вот этой командой askopenfile()

Comment: я не через open открываю поэтому мне сложно

Comment: Если что-то не понятно , то спрашиваете

Answer (score 1):

Ну как пример я думаю сойдет(мне кажется можно как то более экономнее и практичнее, но в голову пока что ничего не идет)

При запуске приложения вы заполняете редактор и после того как вы его забили какие то текстом вы нажимаете кнопку сохранить. После чего у вас программа генерирует название текста и сохраняет его в переменную `self.file_name` в результате последующего редактирования и сохранения файла (естественно не перезагружая программу) вы сохраняете данные в файл которые создали при первом сохранении.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import string
import os


class Main(tk.Tk):
    file_name = ""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.text = tk.Text(self)
        self.text.pack()

        mainmenu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=mainmenu)

        filemenu = tk.Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Сохранить", command=self.func)
        mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Файл", menu=filemenu)

    def func(self):
        if self.file_name:
            with open(self.file_name, "w") as name_read:
                name_read.write(self.text.get("1.0", tk.END))
        else:
            name_txt = "{}.txt".format(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(4)))
            with open(name_txt, "w") as name:
                name.write(self.text.get('1.0', tk.END))
            self.file_name = "{}\{}".format(os.getcwd(), name_txt)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().mainloop()
```

Comment: мой знакомый говорил что по каким-то из атрибутов open ('w','a','r') (если уже файл сохранен, то выдает True или False не помню что именно ) И на основе True или False можно выполнить сохранение файла. Знаете что нибудь про это

Comment: @A.Kross в моем ответе если вы при запуске программы не сохранили файла то `self.file_name` будет равно `False` т.к. данных в ней нету. После того как вы сохранили его первый раз переменная `self.file_name` заполняется данными, а после повторного сохранения вы просто записываете данные в файл который был создан при первом сохранении. Я не совсем понял что имеет ввиду ваш знакомый

Comment: Понял. А можете посоветовать как открыть файл не задавая ему имени.То есть я сначала сохраняю файл через а f=filedialog.asksaveasfile() в одной функции, а потом в другой функции я пытаюсь открыть тот же файл file= open(f,'w') но мне выдает ошибку. Не поможете

Comment: @A.Kross попробуйте вместо `f` написать `f.name` если конечно `f = asksaveasfile()`

Comment: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment

Comment: вот такую ошибку мне выдает.

Comment: ну у вас `f` локальная переменная. Не зная ваш код я не могу ничего сказать